# App crash - how to fix?

Tags: android, crash

I am having a strange phenomenon with Android Studio.
An app that is working without problems in Emulator and on different tested devices, is crashing at launch time (dialogue `"... has stopped" with option 'Open app again'`) on one specific device (Android 7.0).

Until crash happens, the app has successfully called `onCreate()` and done quite some stuff.
Clicking on 'Open app again' launches the app without problem.

Is this a bug in AS maybe?
Here's the output from Logcat:

```
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] Runtime aborting...
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] Aborting thread:
/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 WaitingForDebuggerSend (still starting up)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0xa1f0d000
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | sysTid=10723 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xa7aa6920
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | state=R schedstat=( 1654233000 957016472 1873 ) utm=132 stm=33 core=3 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | stack=0xa79a8000-0xa79aa000 stackSize=1022KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   native: #00 pc 0034f0ad  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+128)
```

Any help will be  greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem disappeared after removing all breakpoints in Android Studio.